# scala speed when using get() method on hash tables? (are temporary Option() objects generated?)

Tags: scala, optimization, jvm, hashtable, temporary-objects

I am converting some code to Scala.  It's code that sits in an inner loop with very large amounts of data so it needs to be fast, and it involves looking up keys in a hash table and computing probabilities.  It needs to do different things depending on whether a key is found or not.  The code would look like this using the "standard" idiom:

```
counts.get(word) match {
  case None => {
    WordDist.overall_word_probs.get(word) match {
      case None => (unseen_mass*WordDist.globally_unseen_word_prob
                    / WordDist.num_unseen_word_types)
      case Some(owprob) => unseen_mass * owprob / overall_unseen_mass
    }
  }
  case Some(wordcount) => wordcount.toDouble/total_tokens*(1.0 - unseen_mass)
}
```

but I am concerned that code of this sort is going to be very slow because of all these temporary Some() objects being created and then garbage-collected.  The Scala2e book claims that a smart JVM "might" optimize these away so that the code does the right thing efficiency-wise, but does this actually happen using Sun's JVM?  Anyone know?

Comment: Have you tested the code?  Don't worry too much until you know there's a problem!  I don't see any red flags.

Comment: Try using this to measure: http://axel22.github.io/scalameter/

Comment: @alex22: Thanks! I've made a note of this. Currently I have other more pressing performance issues (memory especially). I'm doing NLP algorithms and by their nature they create very large tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may happen if you enable [escape analysis](http://java.dzone.com/articles/escape-analysis-java-6-update) in the jvm, enabled with:

```
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
```

on JRE 1.6. Essentially, it should detect objects being created which do not escape the method activation frame and either allocate them on the stack or GC them right after they're no longer needed.

One thing you could do is to micro benchmark your code using the [`scala.testing.Benchmark`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/testing/Benchmark.html) trait. Just extend it with a singleton object and implement the `run` method, compile it and run it. It will run the `run` method multiple times, and measure execution times.

Comment: Didn't know about this method and thought: Cool!. But looking at the source it does not even warm up the JVM.

Comment: Actually, it does - it runs the benchmark `n` times, where `n` is the argument to the main method, and shows all the times. You can then visually see the point at which the JVM is supposed to be warmed up.

Comment: `scala.testing.Benchmark` is deprecated. What is the replacement?

Comment: http://axel22.github.io/scalameter/ should help - integrates nicely with SBT, too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Some` objects will be created (`None` is a singleton). Unless, of course, JVM elides that -- that depends on many factors, including whether or not JVM thinks the code is called all that much.

Anyway, that code is not really the standard idiom. There's even a meme about it: once, one experienced Scala developer was written code like this, when the other one replied "What's this? Amateur hour? Flatmap that sh*t!"

Anyway, here's how I'd rewrite it:

```
( counts 
  get word
  map (_.toDouble / total_tokens * (1.0 - unseen_mass))
  getOrElse (
    WordDist.overall_word_probs
    get word
    map (unseen_mass * _ / overall_unseen_mass)
    getOrElse (unseen_mass * WordDist.globally_unseen_word_prob
                / WordDist.num_unseen_word_types)
  )
)
```

You can then refactor this -- both `getOrElse` parameters could be split in different method with nice names. Since they just return a value without input, they should be pretty fast.

Now, we call just two methods here on `Option`: `map` and `getOrElse`. Here's the beginning of their implementation:

```
@inline final def map
@inline final def getOrElse
```

As the parameter to `getOrElse` is passed by name, it involves an anonymous function creation. And, of course, the parameter to `map` is also a function. Other than that, the chance of these methods getting inlined is pretty good.

So, here's the refactored code, though I don't know enough about it to give good names.

```
def knownWordsFrequency = counts get word map computeKnownFrequency
def computeKnownFrenquency = 
  (_: Int).toDouble / total_tokens * (1.0 - unseen_mass)

def probableWordsFrequency = (
  WordDist.overall_word_probs 
  get word 
  map computeProbableFrequency
)
def computeProbableFrequency = unseen_mass * (_: Double) / overall_unseen_mass

def unknownFrequency = (unseen_mass * WordDist.globally_unseen_word_prob
  / WordDist.num_unseen_word_types)

def estimatedWordsFrequency = probablyWordsFrequency getOrElse unknownFrequency

knownWordsFrequency getOrElse estimatedWordsFrequency
```

Comment: I don't think your example is any kind of standard idiom.  The idiom I present is what I've seen in scala2e.  I personally find your code nearly incomprehensible -- and I've been programming for about 30 years.  The basic problem is that (IMO) it's completely unobvious in your code that any sort of if-then-else is being performed.

Comment: The implementation of getOrElse with an anonymous function creation is just horrible (not your fault but Scala's fault) -- very quick way to kill your performance. I noticed this a few days ago when I started disassembling the compiled Scala code. This is bad bad bad.

Comment: @UrbanVagabond Try using `-optimize` to compile, so that `getOrElse` gets inlined, and the anonymous function disappears. About if-then-else, in my own opinion it _shouldn't_ be there, as it is an implementation detail; `getOrElse` describes well that either we get the value in one way, or else in another. And if you think performance of `getOrElse` is bad, you should see how pattern matching decompiles. Finally... well, let's just say there isn't a single `case Some` or `case None` in "Scala in Depth", whereas `getOrElse` is the second method described.

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry to be responding several months afterwards.  The thing about functional styles like what you're advocating is that many people do not find them especially intuitive in complex constructions.  This is in fact exactly the stated reason for introducing for loops in Scala.  Since Scala is supposed to not ram functional programming down your throat, but allow you to write as you find most clear, it would be nice if doing this didn't introduce lots of inefficiency.  Perhaps the new macro implementation will help.